# Get MethodInfo from two similar methods

Tags: c#

In Entity Framework Core, using C# 6, there are the following 3 methods:

```
public static class EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions {

  public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> Include<TEntity, TProperty>([NotNullAttribute] this IQueryable<TEntity> source, [NotNullAttribute] Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) where TEntity : class;

  public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>([NotNullAttribute] this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, ICollection<TPreviousProperty>> source, [NotNullAttribute] Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) where TEntity : class;

  public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>([NotNullAttribute] this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> source, [NotNullAttribute] Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) where TEntity : class;

}
```

I need to Invoke these methods using generics. For Include I am doing something like this:

```
MethodInfo _include = 
  typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions)
          .GetTypeInfo()
          .GetDeclaredMethods(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include))
          .Single(x => x.GetParameters().Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
          .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));
```

My problem is how to distinguish the 2 ThenInclude methods. There is only one difference which one takes:

```
IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, ICollection<TPreviousProperty>>
```

And the other

```
IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty>
```

BTW, if someone knows a way to simplify my code let me know.

Comment: Why is it important to invoke via generics? There may be an alternate answer other than generics.

Comment: I just decided to provide an overall picture of what I am trying to do in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312437/can-a-string-based-include-alternative-be-created-in-entity-framework-core. It was getting to hard to explain what I am trying to do piece by piece. Basically, I am trying to overcome the fact that Entity Framework Core does not support String Based Include which is very useful for Dynamic Queries.

Comment: You distinguish them by their argument types? You don't know what method to call until you know those. Using `dynamic` may be a lot simpler here than statically finding methods. (`dynamic` can't resolve extension methods, but you get around that by just calling the method statically -- `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ThenInclude(dynamic)` should resolve to the correct method depending on the runtime type of its argument.)